# I am getting error as "Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms" using Selenium 3.1 and Firefox 50

Tags: java, selenium3

I have POM model, Selenium 2.53 with firefox 45 was running fine, but now I want to move to Selenium 3.1 but I am always getting above error when executing test cases. Any help would be great

```
private static WebDriver initFirefoxDriver(String appURL) {
        System.out.println("Launching Firefox browser..");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "C:\\Geeco\\wires.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
        driver.navigate().to(appURL);
        return driver;
}
```

This is how I am instantiating my driver.

Comment: From everything else I've seen, this sounds like a versioning issue, your webdriver and firefox versions are incompatible.

Comment: So  there is any other solution rather than downgrading Firefox ? I mean as a tester we must test on latest version

Comment: I wouldn't say we have to test on the latest version. You have to test on the version(s) being used by consumers/users of the software, or at least the versions you're requested to ensure work! Latest doesn't always equal best, especially if you're sacrificing stability.